# How much of THE iDOLM@STER was based on the games?

Tags: the-idolmaster

(In case there is an confusion, I'm talking about the 2011 series, not Xenoglossia)

I think I heard that Ryuuguu Komachi was formed in THE iDOLM@STER 2, but are there any other key events that are from the game(s), or is the TV series mostly original?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plot in the games does not lend itself to being directly adapted into an anime since it hinges on developing a group of three of the idols at once. As far as the game is concerned, the other idols don't really exist. They pop up on occasion when you have the opportunity to invite others to encores and 5-person songs.

The core concepts and themes for each idol are derived from the games but the precise events are entirely new. Furthermore, the anime is filled with fanbase Easter eggs and references to interactions that the seiyuu have with each other. In fact, many traits of the idols are based on their seiyuu.

Comment: "They pop up on occasion when you" When you... what? :P This seems like a good answer, but I'm just wondering which game(s) you've played to base this answer on.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks. Also, im@s 2, parts of im@s 1